# What happened to Moria?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In *The Lord of The Rings: The Fellowship of The Ring*, the Fellowship passes through the Mines of Moria, which is an evil infested wasteland. It is unknown to Gimli how this happened as he still thought it would be maintained by Dwarves. I've also heard somewhere else in LOTR of someone being referred to as a refuge of Moria. So my question is; how did Moria go from a Dwarven mine to an evil-filled hole? If it mentions this in the book I may have missed it.

Comment: It's not easy sharing an apartment with a Balrog

Comment: Though I've done it :-)

Comment: The appendices at the end of _Return of the King_ are your _mellon_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Dwarves of Moria dug too greedily and too deep and awakened Durin's Bane, a balrog. It drove them out of the mines and slew Durin.